# Не работает машина состояний в группе телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Не работает машина состояний в группе, если в диалоге пользователя с ботом, не в группе то все ок, если запускать в группе, то не переходит к состояниям.Вычитал что вроде как она принципе не может работать в группе, но может есть способ обойти?
Код:

```
class FSMcreatetask(StatesGroup):  # сохранение запрашиваемого перевода в машину состояния
    date = State()
    id = State()
    time = State()
    task = State()
    descriptions = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands="task", state=None)
async def task(message: types.Message):
    print('метка1')
    await FSMcreatetask.date.set()
    await message.answer('Введите день недели задачи в формате ...')
    print('метка2')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMcreatetask.date)
async def load_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    print('метка3')
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['date'] = message.text
        data['id'] = message.chat.id
    await FSMcreatetask.time.set()
    await message.answer('Введите время задачи в формате 24-часовом формате Пример: 00:00')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMcreatetask.time)
async def load_time(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['time'] = message.text
    await FSMcreatetask.task.set()
    await message.answer('Введите задачу')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMcreatetask.task)
async def load_task(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['task'] = message.text
    await FSMcreatetask.descriptions.set()
    await message.answer('Введите название задачи')


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMcreatetask.descriptions)
async def load_task(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['descriptions'] = message.text
    await sql_add_command(state, 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)')  # выводил в базу
    await message.answer('Задача сохранена!')
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Не понимаю где вы это вычитали, что она не работает в группах, но у меня ваш код работает(в группе)

Comment: Единственное странное так это то что я не сразу вижу сообщения бота, он их отправил, но чтобы увидеть сообщение нужно переключится на какой-то другой чат и вернуться обратно. Думаю какая-то бага с самим телеграмом.

Comment: Пробовал выходить из чата группы, не помогает, так и не работает.